# Can I install Windows server and enble Hyper-V on a VM on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hyper-v, ubuntu-14.04

Can I enable Hyper-V role on windows Guest OS(VM) running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I hitting with issue

`Hyper-V cannot be installed: A hypervisor is already running.`

Answer (score 1):

No, Virtualbox needs the Hypervisor all by itself.

Comment: I don't understand you. Can you explain..

Comment: I did answer your question perfectly. If you don't understand, you're the one who needs to be more spesific. What exactly is it that you don't understand. You cannot run Hyper-V on the guest because host needs this property alone to serve the guest.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. Can we do any hack to get it working..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#VT-x_handles_Hyper-V_exclusively